# Spacemacs package ownership

Tags: spacemacs

In the spacemacs documentation for [writing layers](http://spacemacs.org/doc/LAYERS.html), it says that "[o]nly one layer may own a package". This has the consequence, that if you write a layer that requires a package, you have to know whether you can claim ownership of it by writing a `<layer>/init-<package>` function, or if you have to use the `post-init` function for the package to avoid seizing "ownership of a package that was owned by a previously enabled layer".

Is there a function in spacemacs, that takes a package name and tells you if it is owned by any standard spacemacs layer? I know that you technically only need to know if the package is owned by a previously **enabled** layer, but such a function would also help prevent writing unnecessary code.

In case it's of interest, in my particular case, I'm interested in `polymode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function available. You can get this information in two ways.

## Programmatically

You can retrieve the current owner of a package with this function (it requires `helm` layer to be used, it can be easily transposed to `ivy` layer for ivy users).

```
(defun get-package-owner (pkg-symbol)
  "Return the layer owner of the package with name PKG-SYMBOL.
Assumes that the `helm' layer is used (develop branch or version 0.200+ of Spacemacs)"
  (require 'helm-spacemacs-help)
  (helm-spacemacs-help//init)
  (let ((pkg (object-assoc pkg-symbol :name helm-spacemacs-help-all-packages)))
    (when pkg (oref pkg :owner))))

(get-package-owner 'flycheck) ; => syntax-checking
```

## Manually

To get this information non programmatically there is Spacemacs help available on `SPC h SPC` or more specifically here `SPC h p` for just the packages source (it requires either the `helm` or `ivy` layer to be used).

Comment: `(get-package-owner 'flycheck) ; => nil`, `(get-package-owner 'magit) ; => git`. I'm guessing you have the `syntax-checking` layer enabled, while I don't. Is there away to do this for all known ("standard"?) layers, regardless of whether they are loaded?

Comment: Yes it can be done, I'll edit the answer later today. In the meantime you can use `SPC h SPC` to get the answer you are looking for. Tell me if Spacemacs help is enough and I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah, I thought `SPC h SPC` was only for getting the README for a layer, but I see now that entering a package name lists it and in parenthesis its corresponding layer name. Entering for instance `flycheck` results in `flycheck (syntax-checking layer)`, entering `polymode` on the other had doesn't show any results, so it's safe to add (and claim ownership) of it in one of my own layers. Very nice! I'd still appreciate seeing the code to do this, but I'm going to mark this as answered because it's actually exactly what I was looking for to begin with.

Comment: Wait, actually your answer should reflect the information you just gave me. Once you do that, I'll mark your answer as the one that solved the problem :)

Comment: @flooose done :-)

Comment: @flooose "entering polymode on the other had doesn't show any results, so it's safe to add (and claim ownership) of it in one of my own layers." You are right!

Comment: Very nice! One more thing though `SPC h p` doesn't work when I use the latest version of spacemacs from git:  `git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.emacs.d`. Could you be using a development version of spacemacs?

Comment: @flooose indeed it is only available in develop branch, will be in 0.200 I hope to release before the summer (huge release).